# Is it possible to design dynamic logic using pre-discharge NMOS transistor and evaluation done using PMOS?

Tags: digital-logic, cmos, vlsi

Traditionally dynamic logic has a clock input which determines whether the device will work in pre-charge or evaluation phase. PMOS is used as the pre-charge transistor and evaluation is done using NMOS. Is it possible to design dynamic logic using pre-discharge NMOS transistor and evaluation done using PMOS?

Comment: Take a look at these [slides](http://people.ee.duke.edu/~jmorizio/ece261/classlectures/dynamicCMOS.pdf). To investigate further search "zipper cmos logic".

Comment: Thanks @Syed, the slides were helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is certainly possible, as long as propagation delay and/or circuit area are not important design constraints. Since this sounds a bit like a homework question I will leave it at that.